# Slurm: Installing python 3 modules when pip3 not available

Tags: python-3.x

The GPU cluster I'm working off of includes both `python 2.7` and `python 3.5`. `pip` and `easy_install` are both provided to allow local modules to be installed to a `.local` directory. For whatever reason, `pip3` is **not** installed.

How can I install python 3 modules without root access given that `pip3` is unavailable?

Thanks

Comment: How do you choose which Python version you want? through environment modules?

Comment: As simple as python example.py vs. python3 example.py

Comment: See this question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/445906/how-to-get-pip3-without-sudo-privileges

Answer (score -1):

Pycharm community is a free IDE. You can install **pycharm** first. And then, use pycharm to install other modules.

Comment: Does this not require root access?

Comment: @StephenLasky If it's linux system. Try this: sodo snap pycharm-community --classic

Comment: The problem is that this is on a GPU cluster which I do NOT have root access to